# How we can make database resumable in perl script

Tags: database, perl

I have a Perl code which connects with database and scan data from different different table. I face a problem if I lose my connection: it roll back all the transaction. How could I make the Perl script resume the connection and start the process from where the interruption took place? Can I use the Perl to resume the connection or any thing other technique to start the process from where the interruption took place if so could any one guide me with the steps please.

It is actually required because of we have lots of data and takes 1 week to scan all the data and insert in specific table, in between if we run database offline backup it disconnect all the connection and whatever transaction happens it roll back and need to run once again from the beginning.

We can commit the transaction whatever done but challenge is how we can start process from where the interruption took place so we don't require to run from the beginning.

Comment: Database and perl alone can't do that, you'll need some kind of sql proxy which will hold sql sessions for you.

Comment: Maybe I don't deal with data that size enough, but ONE WEEK to run a single transaction, with no commits during that, sounds insane. But maybe others will tell me that is normal

Comment: @mpapec hey thanks for response How I can make sql proxy. Please help me.

Comment: Was not careful enough when reading your question. You're clearly suffering from XY problem, and solution is in different approach and rethinking problem from wider perspective.

Comment: Can you try explaining your table structure and what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you need to drastically alter your approach.

Comment: @Disco3 Thanks for response, Actually I have not a single transaction, have more than once but single transaction took this much time. I can commit any successful transaction but if one transaction took this much time than how we can commit in middle if that transaction not successfully completed. Actually we run this perl script Geo wise like AG(American groups), AP(Asia Pecific) and EMEA(Europe and middle east) in my organization. we are not facing this problem in AP and EMEA since we have less data but AG is our master data and take this much time.

Comment: Hi @AdamTaylor, This is actually to find out SPI(Sensitive personal information) pattern from different different table and remove from their respective table. Basically I have 4 methods fetch,scan1,scan2,notify. fetch method is responsible for fetch details of the account to be scanned. Based on the fetch method scan1 method scan from XYZ table and so on.. Have we any technique is that whatever transaction happened before database disconnection be commit and when I will run perl program it start from where it aborted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on a DB connection to be consistently open for over a day is the wrong approach.

A possible solution involves:

1) Connect to the DB to create a DB Handle. Use an infinite loop and sleep to wait until you have a good db handle. Put this into a subroutine.

2) Put the individual requests for individual tables in a data structure like an array
Execute separate Queries in separate statements in a loop (. 
Check if the dbh is stale before each individual request. Clean and recreate the handle if necessary. Use the subroutine from 1)

Handle breakdowns during a request in EVAL blocks using the "redo" statement to make sure no statement gets skipped.

3) Keep the data between requests either in memory or any non-SQL storage like a Key/Value Store ( Redis,  )

4) Compute whatever needs computation
5) When you have all data for your commit transaction, do.

This solution assumes you don't care about changes between reading and committing back. If you do, you need to LOCK your affected tables first. You probably don't want to lock a table for a week though.

Comment: Can any one tell me shall I use checkpoint restart in this scenario, if yes than please suggest me how I can implement..Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually the problem in one of the method where we are inserting huge data. Suppose I have committed all the data till program got terminated. So can any one tell me is there any way to how I will identify at what place my program terminated and how it will start again inserting data from where it is left.